# How to autoVerifyEmail in aws cognito after the user is signed up. Verify email in Cognito after later state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, email-verification, email-confirmation

My use case:

I want to signup the user in AWS Cognito and want the user to continue through the process without verifying email during the signup process.

To achieve this, I am letting the user continue the process by adding "autoConfirmUser": "true" in Cognito Presignup trigger

In a Cognito post-confirmation trigger, I am sending a CustomVerificationEmail using SES to have him verify the email address.

When the user verifies his email (Status = verified) in SES, I would like to update the EmailVerified to true in Cognito. (Later for forgot password use-case)

How can I achieve this programmatically? Like a Lambda or something triggered by SNS?

I do not want to use AWS CLI like it mentioned in,
[AWS Cognito - User stuck in CONFIRMED and email_verified = false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231797/aws-cognito-user-stuck-in-confirmed-and-email-verified-false)

Answer (score 5):

Please add `autoVerifyEmail` to true in Cognito Presignup trigger.

Observe this [referance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html)

Example code in nodejs

```
"use strict";

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
    event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true; 
    return event;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the easiest way to auto-confirm users!