# Is there a way to confirm email of CONFIRMED users in aws cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Use case I try to achieve in AWS Cognito:

I want users to be able to login in their account regardless whether they confirmed their account or not. However, I want to add a limitation to those that did not confirm it yet and in case they will try to do perform a specific action I will require them to confirm their email in order to proceed further.

I see some people addressed this but rather than trying to achieve this scenario similar to mine (keep email verified to false and let users confirm it) they just tried to auto confirm the email automatically which is something I do not want. [AWS Cognito - User stuck in CONFIRMED and email_verified = false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231797/aws-cognito-user-stuck-in-confirmed-and-email-verified-false)

Can anybody please guide me on this matter whether this is something possible to achieve or else provide some workarounds you implemented for this.